# File saving issue Windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am facing the following issue while performing the save operation on a windows 8.1 phone

a. Let us assume there is a a file named test1.doc is downloaded to a default location in the sdcard. SDCARD - Testfolder

b. We try to edit/open the file using the office 365 present in the phone and try to save it. It does not save it in the same location i.e. TestFolder.

c. It prompts the user to save in the file in the default folder present in phone for eg in the above case since it is a .doc it saves in Documents folder. 
Based on the file extension, it will try to save them in the respective default location i.e. mp3 will be saved under music, .jpg or png will be in picture, .mp4 under videos and .doc,.xls,.txt, ppt under documents. 
Pl. refer to the below link 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn639127.aspx

d. And during save it also modifies the file name by appending (1) to the file. User is also given the option to modify the file name before saving.

Where on the tab and desktop it is allowing us to do the save on the same location. 
I would like to know if it is a know limitation on the windows phone or any thing needs to be done to make the file save in the same location. Any input on this will be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

That is the platform norm (I am not calling it as "limitation"). Every app has access to its own `IsolatedStorage` and media libraries depending on the access requested in manifest.

Comment: Totally agree with Adarsha. It's not a limitation. If you're creating such an app, you can also use `FileSavePicker` to allow the user pick a location from anywhere in the file system. The Office app assumes people would normally save documents in the Documents folder, so they remove the extra step of asking user to choose a location.

Comment: While downloading, we asking it to move to the specific location say testfolder use FileSavePicker. However if the file has been edited it does not save in the same testfolder location. It does the save only in the default Document folder. Is there way to save the file in the same location. Since i need to sync the modified file with the server.